# Kinesis data stream creation failed on cloudformation build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I am new to aws cloud services. I am doing a deploy of a cloudformation template in which I have to deploy a kinesis datastream service which will receive data through an IoT topic rule.
Before introducing this stream as an action of the IoT rule, I introduced in cloud formation file kinesis data stream resource but in stack->events its creation failed during aws deploy. I list its properties:

```
MyKinesisDataStream:
Condition: MyCondition
Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
Properties:
  Name: !Join [ '_', [ !Ref VAR1, !Ref PREFIX, 'mykds'] ]
  RetentionPeriodHours: 24
  ShardCount: !Ref NROFSHARD
```

First of all, I kindly ask if there i a way to obtain more stacktrace or insight about this failure.
I used local aws client cloudformation template validation tool and it confirmed file compliance.

Please feel free to give further advice to edit this question.

Comment: Can you get the error from the CloudFormation error logs?

Comment: How can I get it from clouformation service? Do I have to add a cloudwatch resource and stop automatic rollback?

Comment: From the interface in CloudFormation, filter by `Failed`. If you find your failed stack you can then click the Events tab

Answer (score 0):

The apparent issue which can be  seen in your template is incorrect **indentation**. It should be:

```
MyKinesisDataStream:
  Condition: MyCondition
  Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
  Properties:
    Name: !Join [ '_', [ !Ref VAR1, !Ref PREFIX, 'mykds'] ]
    RetentionPeriodHours: 24
    ShardCount: !Ref NROFSHARD
```

Everything else looks fine, assuming that `VAR1`, `PREFIX` and `NROFSHARD` are correct.